# failed to compile log4cxx in Ubuntu12. error is apr

Tags: logging, ubuntu, log4cxx

Follow instruction with this [link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Log4cxx.html)
include this  `apt-get install libapr1 libaprutil1`

When run `./configure --prefix=/usr`
i am getting error:

```
configure: error: APR could not be located. Please use the --with-apr option.
```

any advice please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need also to run the following:

```
apt-get install libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a script for Ubuntu Server 12.0.4:

```
#!/bin/bash

export APR_PATH=/usr/bin/apr-1-config
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
export TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/tomcat
export INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr

apt-get install libaprutil1-dev make

cd /tmp
rm -Rf tomcat-native-*
tar -zxf $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/tomcat-native.tar.gz
cd /tmp/tomcat-native-*/jni/native

./configure --with-apr=$APR_PATH --with-java-home=$JAVA_HOME --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX
make && make install
```